# Installed Stuff & Cannot Right Click Desktop

Tags: compiz, gnome-tweak-tool

I wanted to change the wallpaper for each of the workstations. After following some very simple instructions I was able to do so. Soon after, I discovered that I could not right click on my desktop. Nothing would happen.

While not entirely necessary it would be nice to have. I have reverted my changes for the time being until I can find a solution for this. I installed Gnome Tweaks and CompizConfig to achieve my wallpaper goal.

My question... Anyway I can use separate wallpapers and maintain normal functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to enable Different Wallpaper For Each Workspace.

Install Compiz Configuration Settings Manager, if you don't have it installed yet.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

or

[image]

Then

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on your keyboard and run:

```
gconf-editor
```

then take a look [At this.](http://joesteiger.com/2011/07/18/enable-different-wallpapers-for-each-workspace-in-unity-ubuntu-11-04/)

Comment: I was able to successfully do that before. Sorry if my original question wasn't clear. After I did this I found that I could not right click on my desktop. Say to add a folder or whatever other functions exists in the desktop right click.